# Does ActivatorUtilities support lifetime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, activator

Does ActivatorUtilities support DI lifetime? For example, I need to create an instance of *IRegistered* interface later with custom params (not from DI).

```
public void Singleton()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<IRegistered, Registered>();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var first = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Registered>(serviceProvider, 10);
    var second = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Registered>(serviceProvider, 10);

    Assert.Equal(first, second);
}

 private interface IRegistered
 {
     public Guid Id { get; }
     public int Value { get; }
 }

 private class Registered : IRegistered
 {
     public Guid Id { get; }
     public int Value { get; }

     public Registered(int value)
     {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid();
         Value = value;
     }
 }
```

in the real world, it can be scoped service which should be created with custom parameters for user HTTP request.

Comment: Short answer: No, Longer answer: Not according to the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ActivatorUtilities.cs,29)

Comment: It's the DI container that supports different lifestyles

Comment: So you are saying that you'd probably like to create two singletons? See the contradiction in it?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras, I thought that the first call CreateInstance will create the singleton instance and the second one will return the instance.

Comment: That should be the case. The point being that if the framework let you create outside of the `serviceProvider` configuration, it would violate both the container's purpose and the singleton purpose. And that's why you can't do it.

Comment: what you want may be the method `GetServiceOrCreateInstance` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.getserviceorcreateinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_GetServiceOrCreateInstance__1_System_IServiceProvider_ - It tries obtaining an instance from the service provider first before actually creating a new instance (if not resolvable).

Comment: @KingKing It doesn’t work because I have args = 10, and DI can't resolve it